# Msbuild createproperty

Tags: msbuild

I have done like this:

```
<Target Name="CreateProperties">                
    <GetAssemblyFileVersionTask strFilePathAssemblyInfo="$(AssemblyInfo)">
        <Output TaskParameter="strAssemblyFileVersion" PropertyName="strAssemblyFileVersion" />
    </GetAssemblyFileVersionTask>
    <Message Text="AssemblyFileVersion = $(strAssemblyFileVersion)" />

    <CreateProperty
      Value="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace( $(strAssemblyFileVersion), '^(\d+)\.(.+)\.\d+$', '$1_$2' ) )">          
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Value"
            PropertyName="rev" />
    </CreateProperty>


    <CreateProperty
        Value="$(ProjName)">
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Value"
            PropertyName="proj" />
    </CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

When I run the msbuild I can see that both rev and proj are alive both inside the target CreateProperties and my other targets in the same msbuild file.

BUT....when I use another msbuild file that is importet in this file it is like they dont exist. The properites are empty. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You have to "pass" properties down to the "helper" proj file. ("SomeCommonLogic.proj" is my "helper" file in the below example)

Note how I pass properties from the "outside" proj file TO the "helper" proj file, via "Properties" in the below sample.

```
  <Target Name="SomeCommonLogicTarget">
    <Message Text="    " />
    <Message Text="    " />
    <MSBuild Projects="..\..\MSBuildCommonLogic\SomeCommonLogic.proj" Targets="SomeTargetInTheHelperFile" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);RevisionNumber=$(SubVersionRevision)" />
  </Target>
```

Also, the "helper" file does **NOT** like relative paths.
You have to convert any relative files to a full path.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <WorkingCheckoutItemGroupForParameterPassing Include=".\MyFile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
<CreateProperty Value="%(WorkingCheckoutItemGroupForParameterPassing.fullpath)">
  <!-- Use the .fullpath value to get the full path to push it into the xsl(document function)  -->
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="WorkingCheckoutFullPath" />
</CreateProperty>
<Message Text=" WorkingCheckoutFullPath = $(WorkingCheckoutFullPath)" />
```

Comment: Note that properties defined with /p are 'global' and do not need to be passed on. Properties created (or even global properties overriden with CreateProperty) still need to be passed like through. Man this caused me such a headache. Great answer!